# Django query parameters not returning None

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a few lines of code in my view that get a query param and then filter based on that parameter.

```
search = request.GET.get('search', None)

if search:
    accounts = UserProfile.objects.filter(fullname__icontains=search).order_by('fullname')
else:
    accounts = UserProfile.objects.all().order_by('fullname')
```

For some odd reason, on my local machine, it appears that when I give a url of something like `localhost/accounts/admin/` or `localhost/accounts/admin/?search=` it works fine -- on my production server, however, it seems to think that the search is an empty string, and then it passes the if/then conditional which returns an empty queryset. `GET:<QueryDict: {u'search': [u'']}>`

Why does python seem to think that this empty string is "something?"

```
>>> x = ''
>>> if x:
...     print "Exists"
... else:
...     print "None"
... 
None

>>> x = u''
>>> if x:
...     print "exists"
... else:
...     print "None"
... 
None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually if you pay close attention the search variable is set to a list that contain an empty unicode string `[u'']` so that why it's evaluated to True:

```
>>> search = [u'']
>>> bool(search)
True
```

And for why you are seeing different behavior between your test and production sadly i'm not sure why !? maybe the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict) can help.

Comment: You're right. I have no idea why there is a difference between my local and prod environments, but this is definitely what's causing the  conditional to evaluate to True. Both are running the same versions of python and Django -- very odd.